# Some of my Android sensors are registered, but do not work

Tags: java, android, sensors, android-sensors

I registered 6 android sensors. Before I register them, I checked out whether the sensor is null or not.

> 11-25 20:21:09.896  10355-10355/ex11.vr.ex11_application I/SensorManagerA﹕ getReportingMode :: sensor.mType = 3
>
> 11-25 20:21:09.976  10355-10355/ex11.vr.ex11_application I/SensorManagerA﹕ getReportingMode :: sensor.mType = 9
>
> 11-25 20:21:09.976  10355-10355/ex11.vr.ex11_application I/SensorManagerA﹕ getReportingMode :: sensor.mType = 1
>
> 11-25 20:21:09.976  10355-10355/ex11.vr.ex11_application I/SensorManagerA﹕ getReportingMode :: sensor.mType = 4
>
> 11-25 20:21:09.986  10355-10355/ex11.vr.ex11_application I/SensorManagerA﹕ getReportingMode :: sensor.mType = 2
>
> 11-25 20:21:09.996  10355-10355/ex11.vr.ex11_application I/SensorManagerA﹕ getReportingMode :: sensor.mType = 5

```
 protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    int delay = SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_UI;
    SensorManager sensors = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    sensors.registerListener(mSensorListener,
            sensors.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION), delay);
    sensors.registerListener(mSensorListener,
            sensors.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY), delay);
    sensors.registerListener(mSensorListener,
            sensors.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), delay);
    sensors.registerListener(mSensorListener,
            sensors.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE), delay);
    sensors.registerListener(mSensorListener,
            sensors.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD), delay);
    sensors.registerListener(mSensorListener,
            sensors.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT), delay);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    SensorManager sensors = (SensorManager)getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
    sensors.unregisterListener(mSensorListener);
}
```

And if one sensor works, then a textview should its content.

```
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if (event.accuracy == SensorManager.SENSOR_STATUS_UNRELIABLE)
            return;
        String output = "";
        float[] v = event.values;
        Log.d("sensor type", Integer.toString(event.sensor.getType()));
        switch (event.sensor.getType()) {
            case Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION:
                output +=
                        "\n azimuth:" + v[0] +
                                "\n pitch:" + v[1] +
                                "\n roll:" + v[2] + "\n";
                TextView txt1 =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                txt1.setText(output);
                break;
            case Sensor.TYPE_GRAVITY:
                output +=
                        "\n X:" + v[0] +
                                "\n Y:" + v[1] +
                                "\n Z:" + v[2] + "\n";
                TextView txt2 =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
                txt2.setText(output);
                break;
            case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
                output +=
                        "\n X:" + v[0] +
                                "\n Y:" + v[1] +
                                "\n Z:" + v[2] + "\n";
                TextView txt3 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView6);
                txt3.setText(output);
                break;
            case Sensor.TYPE_GYROSCOPE:
                output +=
                        "\n X:" + v[0] +
                                "\n Y:" + v[1] +
                                "\n Z:" + v[2] + "\n";
                TextView txt4 =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView8);
                txt4.setText(output);
                break;
            case Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD:
                output +=
                        "\n X:" + v[0] +
                                "\n Y:" + v[1] +
                                "\n Z:" + v[2] + "\n";
                Log.d("content", output);
                TextView txt5 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView10);
                txt5.setText(output);
                break;
            case Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT:
                output +=
                        "\n Lux: "+v[0]+"\n";
                TextView txt6 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView12);
                txt6.setText(output);
                Log.d("content", output);
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

and I registered sensors in onResume method. After that, I executed the application. But here is the log..

> 11-25 20:21:36.016  10355-10355/ex11.vr.ex11_application D/sensor
>   type﹕ 4
>
> 11-25 20:21:36.016  10355-10355/ex11.vr.ex11_application D/sensor
>   type﹕ 9
>
> 11-25 20:21:36.016  10355-10355/ex11.vr.ex11_application D/sensor
>   type﹕ 3
>
> 11-25 20:21:36.086  10355-10355/ex11.vr.ex11_application D/sensor
>   type﹕ 4
>
> 11-25 20:21:36.086  10355-10355/ex11.vr.ex11_application D/sensor
>   type﹕ 1
>
> 11-25 20:21:36.086  10355-10355/ex11.vr.ex11_application D/sensor
>   type﹕ 9
>
> 11-25 20:21:36.086  10355-10355/ex11.vr.ex11_application D/sensor
>   type﹕ 3

Sensors 2, 5 (5 is a light sensor. 2 is a magnetic field sensor.) do not work at all. And I cannot find any error in my code. Is there any specific different way to register magnetic/light sensor?
I tested it with Samsung Galaxy Note 3 device, not with any emulator.